# mutate column based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, recode, mutate

I need to assign a numeric value to a large column of 70+ character variables

When there are a handful of character variables I just mutate by hand  (probably not the best way but it's quick and works) but this is not practical for 70+variables:

```
mutate(df,gender = ifelse(gender=="Female",0, ifelse(gender=="Male",1, 2))
```

I thought it would be best to create a new df(spec) with the 72 variables in column 1 and a number in column 2 to reference:

| speciality | Code |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| e | 5 |
| f | 6 |

...

I can't figure out now how to mutate my data to swap speciality for numeric code.

Any help appreciated - especially if i'm going down the wrong route to do this in the first place

R knowledge is still quite basic. i've tried

```
mutate(df,speciality = ifelse(speciality==spec[,1],spec[,2],0))
```

but get an error

```
Error in env_has(env, name, inherit = TRUE) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will depend on how you want to assign numbers to each value. Here are a few options, using this example data:

```
set.seed(13)

df <- data.frame(speciality = sample(letters[1:4], 8, replace = TRUE))
df
#   speciality
# 1          b
# 2          d
# 3          d
# 4          a
# 5          d
# 6          d
# 7          c
# 8          a
```

If you want to code based on the order values appear in your dataset:

```
#either
mutate(df, speciality = match(speciality, unique(speciality)))

#or
mutate(df, speciality = as.integer(factor(speciality, unique(speciality))))
```

Both of these yield:

```
  speciality
1          1
2          2
3          2
4          3
5          2
6          2
7          4
8          3
```

If you instead want to code based on alphabetical order:

```
#either
mutate(df, speciality = match(speciality, sort(unique(speciality))))

#or
mutate(df, speciality = as.integer(factor(speciality)))
```

Both yield:

```
  speciality
1          2
2          4
3          4
4          1
5          4
6          4
7          3
8          1
```

If you don't care about the order, you can use any of these approaches.

Comment: thanks for answering, i don't quite see how that changes having to manually code 72 variables in the speciality column though?

Comment: I think I misunderstood. How should numbers be assigned to each value of `speciality`? e.g., based on alphabetical order, or order that values appear in the dataset, or some other specified order? Or does the order not matter, you just want a unique number assigned to each unique value in `speciality`?

Comment: @B209978 I've updated my answer; is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

We may use inbuilt `letters` for `match`ing

```
df$speciality <-  with(df, match(speciality, letters))
```